# Requiero sugerencias para compilar este proyecto en Java de la Universidad a medida que avanzo con las opciones del menu el programa se cae

Tags: java

El proyecto es de gestion administrativa para registro de empleados y requiere tener un control de entradas y salidas tambien acceder a todo el sistema siempre y cuando su rol se de recursos humanos
El proyecto dice lo siguiente:

Se le contrata para realizar un sistema que permita llevar el control de empleados de una empresa X. El sistema deberá:
A)
Registro Empleados
B)
Control de Marcas
C)
Cálculo de Planilla
D)
Soporte de Sistema
E)
Realizar informes.
F)
Salir del sistema
El sistema es de carácter administrativo, por lo que únicamente los encargados del Desarrollo Humano deberán tener acceso a la totalidad de del Sistema (A, B, C, D, E)

```
clase main aqui es donde inicio la aplicacion pero a medida que avanzo se cae el proyecto
        import java.time.LocalDate;
        import java.time.Period;
        import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
        import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;
        import java.util.Scanner;
        import java.util.stream.Collectors;
        
        public class Main {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                List<Empleado> listaEmpleados = new ArrayList<>();
                RegistroEmpleados registroEmpleados = new RegistroEmpleados();
                ControlMarcas controlMarcas = new ControlMarcas();
                CalculoPlanilla calculoPlanilla = new CalculoPlanilla();
                SoporteSistema soporteSistema = new SoporteSistema();
                Informes informes = new Informes();
        
                boolean accesoCompleto = obtenerAccesoCompleto(); // Método para obtener el acceso completo
        
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                while (true) {
                    mostrarMenu(accesoCompleto);
        
                    int opcion = scanner.nextInt();
                    scanner.nextLine(); // Consumir el salto de línea pendiente
                    
                    switch (opcion) {
                        case 1 -> {
                            if (accesoCompleto) {
                                registrarNuevoEmpleado(registroEmpleados);
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("No tiene permisos para acceder a esta opción.");
                            }
                        }
                        case 2 -> {
                            System.out.println("----- Control de Marcas -----");
                            realizarControlMarcas(controlMarcas, listaEmpleados);
                        }
                        case 3 -> {
                            if (accesoCompleto) {
                                calcularPlanilla(calculoPlanilla, listaEmpleados);
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("No tiene permisos para acceder a esta opción.");
                            }
                        }
                        case 4 -> {
                            if (accesoCompleto) {
                                realizarSoporteSistema(soporteSistema);
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("No tiene permisos para acceder a esta opción.");
                            }
                        }
                        case 5 -> {
                            if (accesoCompleto) {
                                generarInformes(informes);
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("No tiene permisos para acceder a esta opción.");
                            }
                        }
                        case 0 -> {
                            System.out.println("Saliendo del sistema...");
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                        default -> System.out.println("Opción inválida. Intente nuevamente.");
                    }
                    if (opcion == 0) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        
            // Métodos auxiliares
            private static boolean obtenerAccesoCompleto() {
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Ingrese su rol (Recursos Humanos/RH para acceso completo): ");
                String rolUsuario = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
                return rolUsuario.equals("recursos humanos") || rolUsuario.equals("rh");
            }
        
            private static void mostrarMenu(boolean accesoCompleto) {
                System.out.println("----- Menú de Opciones -----");
                System.out.println("1. Registrar empleado");
                System.out.println("2. Control de marcas");
                if (accesoCompleto) {
                    System.out.println("3. Cálculo de planilla");
                    System.out.println("4. Soporte del sistema");
                    System.out.println("5. Generar informes");
                }
                System.out.println("0. Salir");
                System.out.println("Ingrese el número de la opción deseada: ");
            }
        
            private static void registrarNuevoEmpleado(RegistroEmpleados registroEmpleados) {
                System.out.println("----- Registro de Nuevo Empleado -----");
                Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
                System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre completo del empleado:");
                String nombreCompleto = input.nextLine();
        
                System.out.println("Ingrese la dirección actual del empleado:");
                String direccion = input.nextLine();
                
                System.out.println("Ingrese la fecha de nacimiento del empleado:");
                String fechaNacimiento = input.nextLine();
                
                System.out.println("Ingrese la edad del empleado:");
                int edad = input.nextInt();
                input.nextLine(); // Consumir el salto de línea pendiente
                
                System.out.println("Ingrese la el documento de identidad del empleado:");
                String documentoIdentidad = input.nextLine();
                
                System.out.println("Ingrese la fecha de ingreso del empleado:");
                String fechaIngreso = input.nextLine();
               
                System.out.println("Ingrese la unidad laboral del empleado:");
                String unidadLaboral = input.nextLine();
                
                System.out.println("Ingrese el cargo del empleado:");
                String cargo = input.nextLine();
                
                System.out.println("Ingrese el salario base del empleado:");
                double salarioBase = input.nextDouble();
                input.nextLine(); // Consumir el salto de línea pendiente
        
                // Crear un objeto Empleado con los datos capturados
                Empleado nuevoEmpleado = new Empleado(nombreCompleto, direccion, fechaNacimiento, edad, documentoIdentidad, fechaIngreso, unidadLaboral, cargo , salarioBase);
                // Llamar al método registrarEmpleado de la clase RegistroEmpleados para guardar el nuevo empleado
                registroEmpleados.registrarEmpleado(nuevoEmpleado);
            }
        
            private static void realizarControlMarcas(ControlMarcas controlMarcas, List<Empleado> listaEmpleados) {
                System.out.println("Ingrese el código del empleado:");
                String codigoEmpleado = scanner.nextLine();
        
                if (listaEmpleados.stream().anyMatch(empleado -> empleado.getCodigo().equals(codigoEmpleado))) {
                    System.out.println("¿Desea registrar una entrada o salida? (entrada/salida):");
                    String tipoMarca = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        
                    if (tipoMarca.equals("entrada") || tipoMarca.equals("salida")) {
                        if (tipoMarca.equals("entrada")) {
                            controlMarcas.registrarEntrada(codigoEmpleado);
                            System.out.println("Se ha registrado la entrada del empleado.");
                        } else {
                            controlMarcas.registrarSalida(codigoEmpleado);
                            System.out.println("Se ha registrado la salida del empleado.");
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Opción inválida. Ingrese 'entrada' o 'salida'.");
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Código de empleado no válido. Intente nuevamente.");
                }
            }
        
            private static void calcularPlanilla(CalculoPlanilla calculoPlanilla, List<Empleado> listaEmpleados) {
                System.out.println("----- Cálculo de Planilla -----");
                            
                System.out.println("¿Desea calcular la planilla para un empleado específico o para toda la planilla? (empleado/planilla):");
                String opcionPlanilla = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
                            
                switch (opcionPlanilla) {
                    case "empleado" -> {
                        System.out.println("Ingrese el código del empleado:");
                        String codigoEmpleado = scanner.nextLine();
                                    
                        if (listaEmpleados.stream().anyMatch(empleado -> empleado.getCodigo().equals(codigoEmpleado))) {
                            System.out.println("Ingrese el monto de ventas del empleado:");
                            double ventas = scanner.nextDouble();
                            scanner.nextLine(); // Consumir el salto de línea pendiente
                                        
                            Empleado empleado = obtenerEmpleadoPorCodigo(codigoEmpleado);
                            double salario = calculoPlanilla.calcularSalario(empleado, ventas);
                            System.out.println("El salario del empleado es: " + salario);
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Código de empleado no válido. Intente nuevamente.");
                        }
                    }
                    case "planilla" -> {
                        for (Empleado empleado : listaEmpleados) {
                            System.out.println("Cálculo de planilla para el empleado: " + empleado.getNombreCompleto());
                            System.out.println("Ingrese el monto de ventas del empleado:");
                            double ventas = scanner.nextDouble();
                            scanner.nextLine(); // Consumir el salto de línea pendiente
                                        
                            double salario = calculoPlanilla.calcularSalario(empleado, ventas);
                            System.out.println("El salario del empleado es: " + salario);
                            System.out.println("---------------------------------");
                        }
                    }
                    default -> System.out.println("Opción inválida. Ingrese 'empleado' o 'planilla'.");
                }   
            }
        
            private static void realizarSoporteSistema(SoporteSistema soporteSistema) {
                System.out.println("----- Soporte del Sistema -----");
        
                System.out.println("¿Desea actualizar la escala salarial, los componentes salariales o los usuarios? (escala/componentes/usuarios):");
                String opcionSoporte = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        
                switch (opcionSoporte) {
                    case "escala" -> {
                        System.out.println("Ingrese el nuevo valor para la escala salarial:");
                        double nuevaEscalaSalarial = scanner.nextDouble();
                        scanner.nextLine(); // Consumir el salto de línea pendiente
        
                        soporteSistema.actualizarEscalaSalarial(nuevaEscalaSalarial);
                        System.out.println("La escala salarial ha sido actualizada.");
                    }
                    case "componentes" -> {
                        System.out.println("Ingrese el nuevo valor para las anualidades:");
                        double nuevasAnualidades = scanner.nextDouble();
                        scanner.nextLine(); // Consumir el salto de línea pendiente
        
                        System.out.println("Ingrese el nuevo porcentaje para las ventas:");
                        double nuevoPorcentajeVentas = scanner.nextDouble();
                        scanner.nextLine(); // Consumir el salto de línea pendiente
        
                        System.out.println("Ingrese el nuevo valor para el seguro de vida:");
                        double nuevoSeguroVida = scanner.nextDouble();
                        scanner.nextLine(); // Consumir el salto de línea pendiente
        
                        System.out.println("Ingrese el nuevo porcentaje para el salario escolar:");
                        double nuevoPorcentajeSalarioEscolar = scanner.nextDouble();
                        scanner.nextLine(); // Consumir el salto de línea pendiente
                        
                                        soporteSistema.actualizarComponentesSalariales(nuevasAnualidades, nuevoPorcentajeVentas, nuevoSeguroVida, nuevoPorcentajeSalarioEscolar);
                        System.out.println("Los componentes salariales han sido actualizados.");
                    }
                    case "usuarios" -> {
                        System.out.println("¿Desea crear, modificar o eliminar un usuario? (crear/modificar/eliminar):");
                        String opcionUsuario = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        
                        switch (opcionUsuario) {
                            case "crear" -> {
                                System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre de usuario:");
                                String nombreUsuario = scanner.nextLine();
        
                                System.out.println("Ingrese la contraseña:");
                                String contrasena = scanner.nextLine();
        
                                soporteSistema.crearUsuario(nombreUsuario, contrasena);
                                System.out.println("El usuario ha sido creado.");
                            }
                            case "modificar" -> {
                                System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre de usuario que desea modificar:");
                                String nombreUsuario = scanner.nextLine();
        
                                System.out.println("Ingrese la nueva contraseña:");
                                String nuevaContrasena = scanner.nextLine();
        
                                soporteSistema.modificarUsuario(nombreUsuario, nuevaContrasena);
                                System.out.println("El usuario ha sido modificado.");
                            }
                            case "eliminar" -> {
                                System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre de usuario que desea eliminar:");
                                String nombreUsuario = scanner.nextLine();
        
                                soporteSistema.eliminarUsuario(nombreUsuario);
                                System.out.println("El usuario ha sido eliminado.");
                            }
                            default -> System.out.println("Opción inválida. Ingrese 'crear', 'modificar' o 'eliminar'.");
                        }
                    }
                    default -> System.out.println("Opción inválida. Ingrese 'escala', 'componentes' o 'usuarios'.");
                }
            }
        
            private static void generarInformes(Informes informes) {
                System.out.println("----- Generar Informes -----");
        
                System.out.println("¿Desea generar un informe de control de marca, empleados por unidad, tiempo laborado por empleado o planilla? (marca/unidad/tiempo/planilla):");
                String opcionInforme = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        
                switch (opcionInforme) {
                    case "marca" -> {
                        System.out.println("Ingrese el código del empleado para el que desea generar el informe:");
                        String codigoEmpleado = scanner.nextLine();
        
                        String informeMarca = informes.generarInformeMarca(codigoEmpleado);
                        System.out.println(informeMarca);
                    }
                    case "unidad" -> {
                        System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre de la unidad para la que desea generar el informe:");
                        String nombreUnidad = scanner.nextLine();
        
                        String informeUnidad = informes.generarInformeUnidad(nombreUnidad);
                        System.out.println(informeUnidad);
                    }
                    case "tiempo" -> {
                        System.out.println("Ingrese el código del empleado para el que desea generar el informe:");
                        String codigoEmpleado = scanner.nextLine();
        
                        String informeTiempo = informes.generarInformeTiempo(codigoEmpleado);
                        System.out.println(informeTiempo);
                    }
                    case "planilla" -> {
                        System.out.println("¿Desea generar un informe de planilla para un empleado específico o para toda la planilla? (empleado/planilla):");
                        String opcionPlanilla = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        
                        switch (opcionPlanilla) {
                            case "empleado" -> {
                                System.out.println("Ingrese el código del empleado para el que desea generar el informe:");
                                String codigoEmpleado = scanner.nextLine();
        
                                String informePlanillaEmpleado = informes.generarInformePlanillaEmpleado(codigoEmpleado);
                                System.out.println(informePlanillaEmpleado);
                            }
                            case "planilla" -> {
                                String informePlanillaTotal = informes.generarInformePlanillaTotal();
                                System.out.println(informePlanillaTotal);
                            }
                            default -> System.out.println("Opción inválida. Ingrese 'empleado' o 'planilla'.");
                        }
                    }
                    default -> System.out.println("Opción inválida. Ingrese 'marca', 'unidad', 'tiempo' o 'planilla'.");
                }
            }
        
            private static Empleado obtenerEmpleadoPorCodigo(String codigoEmpleado) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
            }
        }
    Aun faltan mas clases pero creo que en estas es donde me da mas problemas
    solo puedo acceder y guardar los datos del
```

empleado

Esto es lo que marca el [netbeans](/questions/tagged/netbeans)

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'soporte' could not be parsed at index 0 at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2052) at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1954) at java.base/java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:430) at Empleado.(Empleado.java:42) at Main.registrarNuevoEmpleado(Main.java:162) at Main.main(Main.java:39)

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta o duda?. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. ¿Qué errores te da? ¿Qué significa "se cae"?

Comment: Mis disculpas soy nuevo aqui y apenas comienzo con Java. Los errores me ocurren cuando trato de calcular la planilla asi como en generar informes y en la opcion de soporte sistema, de igual manera si quiero asignar un codigo al empleado nuevo no lo guarda y ahi se corta la ejecucion del programa a eso me refiero con que se cae

Comment: Esto es lo que marca el NetBeans 
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'soporte' could not be parsed at index 0
 at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2052)
 at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1954)
 at java.base/java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:430)
 at Empleado.<init>(Empleado.java:42)
 at Main.registrarNuevoEmpleado(Main.java:162)
 at Main.main(Main.java:39)

Comment: A los enlaces que te dejó el buen @MauricioContreras, le agrego una lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Edita la pregunta y agrega lo que hiciste y el error que te generó, de ese modo, vamos directo al problema que tienes en lugar de jugar a los detectives de bugs, se ahorra tiempo y es un win win para ti y para quien desea darte una mano. Saludos.

Comment: el error indica que en ves de obtener un dato que pueda ser procesado como fecha , estas obteniendo un dato llamado "soporte" , tal vez te as equivocado en digitar ese dato en el campo de fecha